It is not possible to capture specific web links. Unexpected behavior in my Android browser app
I have created a minimal version to check this error.
The app declares in its manifest.xml an activity-alias that points to the only activity of the app,
Manifest.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        ...>

        <activity
            android:name="com.dev.testingcustomtabshost.IntentDispatcher"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|smallestScreenSize" />

        <activity-alias
            android:name=".EntryPoint"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:targetActivity="com.dev.testingcustomtabshost.IntentDispatcher">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_BROWSER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>
    </application>

</manifest>

The activity is the minimum expression that allows checking if the app is called with browser links:
IntentDispatcher.kt:
class IntentDispatcher : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Log.d("BrowserExperiments", "IntentDispatcher onCreate")
        Toast.makeText(this, intent.data.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}

Now, we set the app as the device's default browser.
In this scenario, when we try to open links from the classroom app, we find two answers depending on the type of link.
The link type that works:

The link type that works opened in the app:

The link type that not works:

While testing, I found something very strange. If I add this dependency in gradle:
debugImplementation("com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.14")

With this dependency in gradle, it DOES work, although only in the debug build variant. However, this dependency has nothing to do with intent management.
I appreciate any ideas to capture those types of links, greetings.
